# HTTP Options method is not working as expected

Tags: rest, jersey, wadl

I have a Jersey 2.x application running in tomcat. All the method implementations are working as expected, and even I am able to get WADL by navigating to http://{host}:{port}/JerseyRESTWebapp/ws/rest/application.wadl.
Everything is great so far.

Now, Out of curiosity I tried navigating to  http://{host}:{port}/JerseyRESTWebapp/ws/rest/employees URL using using HTTP OPTIONS method expecting i will get **405 Method not allowed** but i got the **200 OK** and response body contains the **WADL**. Can someone let me know why is this happening? I am using POSTMAN chrome extension as REST client.

Also in the Response **Allow Header**, i am getting **POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD**. I am missing PUT method here. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the resource discovery works by default. It's implemented to follow the spec in regards to OPTIONS resource discovery

> This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

If you want to disable the WADL, you can by setting the property `ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE` to true.

If you're curious about how this is implemented, check out the source for the [`WadlModelProcessor`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/ea6379765194eb4a14d03149202be56ce7928965/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/wadl/processor/WadlModelProcessor.java). It goes through all the resource models and adds an extra OPTIONS resource method. You can read more about the `ModelProcessor` in the Jersey docs [Programmatic API for Building Resources](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html)